# Only getting positive values for induced voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, induction

We have to draw a voltage over time graph for the induced voltage in a coil for 2 whole turns.

$N = 10$
$B = 30mT$
$A = 100cm^2$

The coil is rotating at 20Hz

We have the formula:
$2πNBAfsin(2πfT)$

Every solution I get is positive and just rising with time. It should be a sine curve.

For example:

$U(\frac1{10}) = 2π \times 10 \times 0.03T \times 0.01m^2 \times 20Hz \times \sin(2π \times 20Hz \times 1/10s) = 0.0820$

Comment: How are we supposed to evaluate your work if you don't show it?

Comment: What is there to show?  A picture of 1 line with the numbers plucked into the formula wouldn't really help much.

Comment: A list of T values and the corresponding voltage that you calculated would help.

Comment: 1 /40 second - - > 0.021V; 1/20 second - - >  ~0.041V; 3/40 second - - > 0.062V; 1/10 second - - > 0.082V; that, from my understanding, should be every half of a turn for 2 turns

Comment: Does T stand for time or turns?

Comment: The T stands for the time

Comment: Then why do you have $\sin(2\pi T)$?

Comment: The effective area is the normal area A times the cos(angle), the angle you can write as ω*T and ω is the same as 2πf*T

Comment: Okay, show your calculations for 1/10 second --> .082V (put it in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's taken a lot of back-and-forth in the comments, and I *still* had to connect a few more dots on my own, but I calculated the value of  $2\pi * 10 * 0.03T * 0.01m^2 * 20Hz * \sin(2\pi * 20Hz * (1/10)s°)$ and got $.008202$, so that seems to be the error. Your formula doesn't say to take $2\pi * 10 * 0.03T * 0.01m^2 * 20Hz * \sin(2\pi * 20Hz * (1/10)s°)$, it says to take $2\pi * 10 * 0.03T * 0.01m^2 * 20Hz * \sin(2\pi * 20Hz * (1/10)s)$. There is no degree symbol in the formula.

$2\pi fT$ has dimensions of Hz times seconds, which cancels out, giving no units. When a trigometric function, such as sine, is taken of a dimensionless quantity (as opposed to a quantity given as having the units of degrees), it's generally understood to be radians.

Answer (score 0):

If there no sin, it meant either you missed up your coordinate set up, or forgot the sin somewhere. (Assuming the sin indicated the oscillating current.) Notice that the current this case was practically addition, and the only operation possibly involved was derivative. So the short answer was you did something very wrong.

However, it's also possible that the answer sheet or the formula you used took the time average, which was a completely different case.

Comment: http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electromagnetic%20induction/text/Induced_emf_in_a_rotating_coil/index.html     you can look at this way to make the formula, the way we did it was very similar. Also the formula was given as correct so until now I did not doubt that

Comment: @Sett It's time average, your question was about the vocabulary r.m.s. (see here: http://www.practicalphysics.org/explaining-rms-voltage-and-current.html  ) rather than anything to do with EM.

Comment: So I am just using the wrong formula? If so what's the right one?

Comment: @Sett There's nothing wrong, the one independent of time was provide as r.m.s. , if you confused about that, try use dictionary rather than mathematics.